# Oracle SQL+ Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a rental system for a shop I'm setting up. One of the queries I need is to find the customers that have rented the most in the last 12 months. I have date_out and date_in columns and a number to represent the number of rents by a customer.

Tables: customer (columns: name, phone) & Transaction (date_out, date_in)

I'm inserting the dates with TO_DATE.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Edit: Currently its only displaying 1 as rent_count instead of what I inputted 8 for num_of_rents.

Comment: Please add your table structure and some sample data to your question

Comment: Tables: Customer (columns: name, phone, num_of_rents) Transaction (columns: date_out, date_in) date insertion: INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_T VALUES (TO_DATE('24-MAY-2006','DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('23-AUG-2011','DD-MON-YYYY'));

Comment: Please update your question and don't add that much code in comments.

Comment: Sample results would also be good, to see _how_ you're trying to count them.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_name, count(num_of_rents) as rent_count
from customers
where (SYSDATE - customer_DOB) <= 365
group by customer_name
order by rent_count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Are those your actual tables, if so they are not fit for purpose, at minimum you need some sort of link between the two.

At a minimum you would need something along these lines.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (customer_id number(8), customer_name VARCHAR2(30), phone VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TABLE rents (customer_id number(8), rent_id number(8), date_from DATE, date_to DATE);

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, phone) VALUES (1, 'Test Customer', '1234');

INSERT INTO rents (customer_id, rent_id, date_from, date_to) VALUES (1,1,TO_DATE('01/03/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('02/03/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO rents (customer_id, rent_id, date_from, date_to) VALUES (1,1,TO_DATE('01/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('05/04/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO rents (customer_id, rent_id, date_from, date_to) VALUES (1,2,TO_DATE('16/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE('17/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY'));

SELECT customer_name, count(rent_id) FROM customers 
  JOIN rents on customers.customer_id = rents.customer_id 
 WHERE DATE_TO BETWEEN SYSDATE-365 AND SYSDATE
 GROUP BY customer_name;
```

You will need to tweek the WHERE clause depends on what constitutes a rent in you context i.e. a rent which just starts in the period, one which ends in the period or both.